# Add new field which is the size of another field of the document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and I would like to ask how to make a new field for the element, which represents for the size of another field in that element. For example:
- I have the element such like:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("57e1ffcb94d9ae534869c6cd"), 
  "url" : "http://www.nytimes.com", 
  "verticals" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12 ] 
}
```

I want to add new field say "numadx" which is the size of "verticals" array, in this case, it's 6. And the result can be:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("57e1ffcb94d9ae534869c6cd"), 
  "url" : "http://www.nytimes.com", 
  "verticals" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12 ] 
  "numadx" : 6
}
```

I use the command in the terminal:

```
db.test.update({},{$set:{numadx:{$size: "$verticals"}}},{multi:true})
```

but it return the error:

> "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$size' in 'numadx.$size' is
>   not valid for storage."

Can someone help me :D ? I do this for sorting the elements in this collection based on numadx field, which helps me know the least to the most number of verticals values of these elements in collection.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently in MongoDB you cannot update a document using some calculated value in that document. Also, Bob is correct that `$size` is not an operator recognized by the `update()` command.

Having said that, there is a way to achieve what you want using `mongo` shell scripting:

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{numadx:doc.verticals.length}})
})
```

This script will go into each document in your collection, and set the `numadx` field using the values of the current document that is accessible in the `doc` variable.

You can modify the `find()` query there to process only a subset of your data, otherwise it will run for every document in your collection.

For more information, please see:

- [Javascript forEach method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)
- [Write Scripts for the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Comment: oh thank you, it works smoothly. Oh I've seen that we can't use $size in the update() command xD thanks alot.

Comment: Don't do this. It is very bad for performance and Can cause race condition.

Comment: Very bad performance...

Answer (score 1):

`$addFields` is a [new feature in Mongo 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) that adresses the question:
it lets you update the record of the collection  by  storing the product of the aggregation inside the record

```
db.collection.aggregate(   
     [ {          
          "$addFields": {  "numadx": { $size: "$verticals" } }       
        },
        { "$out":"collection"}
     ]    
)
```

Comment: As at MongoDB 3.4, the `$out` stage  can only [create a new collection or replace an existing one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#behaviors) so this isn't a viable solution for updating an existing document.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think $size is an update operator in MongoDB.  The update operators are https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/.  I've never seen $size used anywhere other than in a find like

```
db.test.find( { verticals: { $size: 6 } } );
```

I think its impossible to use that in an update.  You are going to need to explicitly read the record and jack in your new array.

Comment: Oh I see, but I still can not get the size of that array and update it into a new field for that element xD